# Paging and locking in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have seen lots of answers about paging in Oracle using rownum or ranking analytic functions.  However, I specifically want to apply locking with these paged results.  The issue is that because most paging hacks in Oracle use in-line views, applying `for update` is illegal.

So is there a way to perform both, preferably in the same SQL statement?

An example of what we try now...

```
select * 
from (
    select ...
    from t
    where ...
    order by ...
)
where rownum <= ? 
for update
```

The error we get is `ORA-02014:, cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.`

Comment: Why do you want to lock the resulting rows? Also, what exactly have you tried? I'm pretty sure you can use FOR UPDATE with a query even if it uses ROWNUM or analytic functions - but post your query and we can see.

Comment: As for why, I develop a O/RM solution (Hibernate) and this need arises from that.  There are cases where we are provided (1) some sql, (2) some paging limits, and (3) some locking requirements and we need to apply those together.  This is easy on most databases because most databases have first-class support for paging.

Comment: The error I keep getting is: `ORA-02014:, cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.`.  It is not the use of rownum/analytics specifically that causes the problem; the problem, as I understand it, is the fact that in order to properly limit rows using rownum/analytics one must use inline views, and then Oracle complains about FOR UPDATE in conjunction with the inline view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an example of what you can do

```
SQL> create table t as select object_id, owner, object_name, created from all_objects where rownum <= 100;

Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> select *
  2    from t
  3   where rowid in
  4         (select rid
  5            from (select rowid rid, row_number() over(order by object_id) rn from t)
  6           where rn between 11 and 20)
  7     for update;

OBJECT_ID OWNER OBJECT_NAM CREATED
--------- ----- ---------- ---------
       20 SYS   ICOL$      06-MAR-11
       15 SYS   UNDO$      06-MAR-11
       17 SYS   FILE$      06-MAR-11
       13 SYS   UET$       06-MAR-11
       19 SYS   IND$       06-MAR-11
       14 SYS   SEG$       06-MAR-11
       21 SYS   COL$       06-MAR-11
       16 SYS   TS$        06-MAR-11
       12 SYS   FET$       06-MAR-11
       18 SYS   OBJ$       06-MAR-11

10 rows selected.
```

Comment: Marcin, that is not very different from what we do currently.  But our attempts lead to `ORA-02014:, cannot select FOR UPDATE from view with DISTINCT, GROUP BY, etc.`

Comment: Please notice that in my example I am not selecting from inline view; the subselect appears only in the where clause. That makes a difference.

Comment: Will have to try and adapt this approach to our situation.  We have an incoming SQL statement, so its a bit more complicated (isn't it always ;)

Comment: I have tried implementing this using rownum rather than analytic functions, but it works only in certain cases.  To your knowledge should this work using rownum as well?  The reason I did it that way is that this is a generic method.  It accepts SQL string and "adjusts it" for paging.  So its simply easier to perform the adjustment using rownum.  But if using the analytic functions would magically make this work more consistently, I'll do the work.  Not enough characters.  SQL in next comment

Comment: The SQL where it falls down for me is `select ... from t where rowid in (select rowid__ from (select rowid rowid_ from t order by object_id) where rownum > ? and rownum <= ?) order by object_id for update`.  The `?` are JDBC bind parameters which get bound properly.  Also, I found the repeating of the order by was necessary or else the ultimately returned results were not ordered.

Comment: Just to try, I went ahead and attempted using the analytic functions.  They work better.  But still get problems.  Really hate that Oracle does not support this.

Comment: The condition "rownum > ?" is very tricky - for parameter > 0 it will give you 0 rows. Here's an interesting discussion on ROWNUM pseudocolumn: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:948366252775

Comment: I went ahead and marked this as the "correct answer" because I think it is the best general approach I am going to get with Oracle.